# ¿Como puedo mostrar el resultado de una consulta en una modal Bootstrap 5 en Symfony 5?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, modal, symfony5

Tengo maquetada en mi plantilla una tabla que muestra diferentes registros (Idéntica al archivo **index.html.twig** cuando haces un CRUD en Symfony 5). En una de las columnas tengo un botón para **mostrar** a través de una modal de Bootstrap 5 la información del registro. En esa modal, quiero realizar una consulta en el momento del click y mostrar la información almacenada en la base de datos. Se que tengo que utilizar AJAX para realizar dicha petición pero no se como configurar el controlador del Backend para que la información se me mueste en la plantilla. Con el código que he puesto, Symfony me lanza el error: Variable "Mostrar" does not exist. Al menos me gustaría saber porque no me reconoce la variable. (Creo que es porque la aplicación no encuentra la ruta del controlador)
Agradecería mucho la ayuda. Gracias.

**Controlador:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Articulo;
use App\Repository\ArticuloRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ModalController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/modal_mostrar", name="modal_mostrar", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function mostrar_datos_modal(Request $request): Response
    {
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $hola = "Hola que tal";
        }

        return $this->render('includes/_modal_mostrar.html.twig', [
            'mostrar' => $hola,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Plantilla de la modal:**

```
<!-- Full screen modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalFull" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Artículo</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Aqui dentro colocar la información de la bd. Ver si es necesario utilizar AJAX.
        <h1>{{ mostrar }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Petición AJAX:**

```
//Peticiones AJAX 1
function ajax_modal_mostrar(id) {
    var ruta = Routing.generate('modal_mostrar');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ruta,
        data: ({id: id}),
        aync: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data['modal_mostrar']);
        }
    });
}
```

**Tabla index.html.twig:**

```
<table class="table text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Categoría</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Resuelto</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for articulo in articulos %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ articulo.titulo }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.categoria }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.tipo }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.fecha ? articulo.fecha|date('Y-m-d') : '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.resuelto ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="ajax_modal_mostrar({{ articulo.id }})" id="btn_modal_mostrar" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalFull">Mostrar</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" {# href="{{ path('articulo_edit', {'id': articulo.id}) }}" #}>Editar</>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">No se han encontrado registros</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te daré un ejemplo:
Partimos que tienes una vista con una tabla similar a la que expones, y necesitamos que al hacer click en el botón detalles (Mostrar), se lance el dialogo modal cargando vía ajax el contenido de un fragmento de vista `twig` que representa los detalles de un articulo.

```
<table class="table text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Categoría</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Resuelto</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for articulo in articulos %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ articulo.titulo }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.categoria }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.tipo }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.fecha ? articulo.fecha|date('Y-m-d') : '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.resuelto ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary lnkModalReader" data-src="{{ path('articulo_detalle', {'id':articulo.id}) }}">Mostrar</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" {# href="{{ path('articulo_edit', {'id': articulo.id}) }}" #}>Editar</>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">No se han encontrado registros</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Este action retorna el fragmento de vista `twig` que representa los detalles de un artículo (esa es la única función de este action).

```
public function articuloDetalleAction(Request $request) {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $articulo= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Articulo::class)->find($request->query->getInt('id'));
            if (is_null($articulo)) {
                return new Response("El articulo seleccionado no existe", 404);
            }

                
            return $this->render('articulo/_detalles.html.twig', array(
                        'articulo' => $articulo
            ));
        } else {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("Recurso no encontrado");
        }
    }
```

Por último el código js, y su interpretación:
Básicamente este javacript hace lo siguiente, todo elemento de tipo `<a>` que tenga clase `lnkModalReader` al hacerle click, construirá un dialogo modal (algo puntual esto es bootstrap 3 :-( ) y cargará en un div con id="contenedorForm" dentro del `body` del dialogo vía ajax un contendio html cuyo recurso está ubicado en el `data-src` del elemento cliqueado, es decir de la etiqueta  en tu tabla, básicamente: se cargará el contenido retornado por el action `articuloDetalleAction`. El código js es más extenso de lo normal porque usa el plugin Pace para notificar al usuario del progreso de la petición ajax, así como notificación de errores.

```
$('#vistas').on('click', 'a.lnkModalReader', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var url = $(this).data('src');
        var titulo = $(this).data('original-title');

        Pace.track(function () {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
            }).done(function (data) {
                $(document.body).find('#modalReader').remove();
                $(document.body).append("<div id='modalReader' class='modal fade' tabindex='-1'  role='dialog'><div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header bg-primary'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Cerrar'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h5 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Resumen</h5></div><div class='modal-body'><div id='contenedorForm' class='container-fluid'></div></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-flat' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button></div></div></div></div>");
                if (titulo !== undefined) {
                    $(".modal-title").html('<strong>' + titulo + '</strong>');
                }

                $("#contenedorForm").html(data);
                $('#modalReader').modal({
                    keyboard: false,
                    backdrop: 'static'
                }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(document.body).find('#modalReader').remove();
                });
            }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                    toastr.error("Su sesión ha expirado. No es posible realizar la operación.", '', {
                        timeOut: 2500,
                        preventDuplicates: false,
                        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                        onHidden: function () {
                            window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    toastr.error(jqXHR.responseText, '', {
                        timeOut: 3000,
                        preventDuplicates: false,
                        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                        progressBar: true,
                        showDuration: 800,
                        hideDuration: 400,
                        extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                        showEasing: "swing",
                        hideEasing: "linear",
                        showMethod: "fadeIn",
                        hideMethod: "fadeOut",
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

Te explico el `done` de la petición ajax línea por línea:

**Primero**, se elimina del body de la página cualquier div con id=¨modalReader¨; debido a que este es el div que se convertirá en diálogo modal y así evitamos que se pueda quedar en tu página una ves cerrado el modal ese div, aunque en  el hide del modal se debería destruir el mismo.

```
$(document.body).find('#modalReader').remove();
```

Segundo, le adicionamos al body de tu página una estructura `html` con el formato de un dialogo modal de boostrap (en este caso te recuerdo boostrap3), cuyo id="modalReader", y con la particularidad que en el div que sirve de body al futuro modal dialog (estructura html anterior) existe un div con id="contenedorForm" que será el que alojará el contenido de la respuesta `ajax`, es decir el fragmento de vista `twig` con los detalles del artículo.

```
$(document.body).append("<div id='modalReader' class='modal fade' tabindex='-1'  role='dialog'><div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header bg-primary'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Cerrar'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h5 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Resumen</h5></div><div class='modal-body'><div id='contenedorForm' class='container-fluid'></div></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-flat' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button></div></div></div></div>");
```

**Tercero**, agregarle el resultado de la petición ajax al div con id="contenedorForm", como te expliqué anteriormente es el fragmento twig devuelto por el action y que representa los detalles del artículo. Tu variable `data` claro que tiene que contener el resultado del fragmento de vista twig.

```
$("#contenedorForm").html(data);
```

**Cuarto**, solo resta convertir el html agregado al body de tu página (es decir el div con id="modalReader") en un dialogo modal de boostrap:

```
$('#modalReader').modal({
                        keyboard: false,
                        backdrop: 'static'
                    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(document.body).find('#modalReader').remove();
                    });
```

Fíjate como declaro el `on('hidden.bs.modal')` del modal, y en el mismo se elimina el div con id="modalReader" para garantizar que al cerrarse el modal, se destruya el div. Esto permite abrir y cerrar cuantas veces desees el modal sin recargar la página y nunca quedará el html añadido al body de tu página una vez se cierre el diálogo.

Disculpa si fui reiterativo, trato de explicar lo mejor posible.

Comment: Directamente todo el html que se añade con $(document.body).append() no funciona y el parámetro data me devuelve el contenido en codigo de lo que hay en _detalles.html.twig en vez del resultado de la consulta. Entiendo la función del código pero no termino de entenderlo. Me vendría bien una explicación más detallada. Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: @Adrián trataré de explicarte nuevamente sobre la misma respuesta.

Comment: La explicación fue perfecta, muchas gracias. Ahora necesito saber como resolver varias cosas más.

Comment: @Adrián en ese caso puedes aceptar la respuesta y para otras dudas no relacionadas a esta, postea otra pegunta